# Google Earth Engine: Calculate milliseconds since epoch from datetime of uploaded shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, table, date, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to get the milliseconds since epoch of thousands of points, each with different timestamps. Here is what I believe I need to do, but my Google Earth Engine knowledge is limited and I can't find a good way to do this:

1. Upload a shapefile with a column containing date/time (DONE)
2. Set the time/date string as a Date column (using `.set()`) and convert it to a Date object with `ee.Date()`)
3. Calculate the "time" column using `.millis()` on the column created in step 2

My best effort so far has been this:

```
var times = points.set('timestamp', ee.Date(points.select('timestamp')).millis());
```

where:
(timestamp = the "date/time" column, formatted as dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss)
(points = name of uploaded shapefile table, the FeatureCollection)

The console error says:
*FeatureCollection (Error)
Date: Cannot interpret  as a Date.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided a complete example to test against, but it sounds like the problem is that you're trying to process *features in a collection* but as written your code is operating on *the collection itself.* Earth Engine does not support working with feature properties in “array programming” fashion where an entire column is manipulated as a value; you must always `map` over the collection to modify a property for each feature in the collection. Thus, instead of

```js
var times = points.set('timestamp', ee.Date(points.select('timestamp')).millis());
```

you operate on each feature like

```js
var times = points.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.set('timestamp', ee.Date(feature.get('timestamp')).millis());
});
```

Note that within the mapping function I have replaced `points` with `feature` (the individual feature) and `.select()` (filter properties on an entire collection) with `.get()` (retrieve the *actual value* of a property on the feature).